# Including etc or dots inside a reference in latex

Tags: bibtex

Is there a way to include etc or dots (...) when citing with bibtex? I want my reference to appear like below but can't figure out how.

Several publication [1,2,3,4,**etc**] or [1,2,3,4...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The optional argument of `\cite` can be used to add the dots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Several publications \cite[\dots]{a,b,c}

\newpage

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{a} A.

\bibitem{b} B.

\bibitem{c} C.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: For old-style lovers, one  could also use `\cite[\&c.]{a,b,c}`.